# How to set the DB as parameter in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

I'm using ReportBuilder 3.0 for creating report in reporting services 2008. I have many DB with the same tables (different data) and I created a report that can be applied to all these DB. I want to add a parameter to choose the database so the user can choose the DB from which getting the data.
I created a parameter (named "DB") with the name of the DBs as avilable values, but I can't use the parameter in the queries as I was expected:

```
SELECT *
FROM @DB.[dbo].[TableName]
```

That query (used in a dataset) doesn't work.

There's a way to set the DB as a parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TSQL, you would use dynamic sql to do this ([EXEC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)(@CMD)).  I doubt report builder will allow you to do this.  There are [security risks](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) to this.